# UIVisualEffectView inside Tableview Cells issue

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

`UIVisualEffectView` causes performance issues in `UITableViewCell`.

I'm using very simple `UIVisualEffectView` inside `UITableViewCell` 
what I did was adding `UIVisualEffectView` from storyboard to fit the cell 
and give it some background so this background color will be blurred.

When I scroll the tableview fast, it doesn't scroll smoothly and that most likely because of `UIVisualEffectView` inside each cell

1. Is using `UIVisualEffectView` inside every cell is a bad idea ?
2. What is the best practice for that ?

Comment: It's weird that it's not smooth, it should be ok to use `UIVisualEffectView` in table view cell; can you show any configuration you're doing? Like what you do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the cell class?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio sorry for late response , after some workarounds I thought I passed this problem but I didn't
What I did was adding visual effect view in the story board and create outlet from this view and in the CollectionViewCell class inside awakeFromNib method I set the visual effectView BackGround to the color I want and set any other view background color to clear color